# How to avoid updating files in S3 if the file content hasn't been changed

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a bunch of files in an existing local directory to an S3 bucket on a daily basis
I would like to re-upload only if newer files have been added or existing files have been modified in my local directory.

For example,
I have a local image directory that contains the following image files, image1, image2, image3

Day 1: Uploaded all the 3 images to s3

Day 2: Added a new file called image4 in the local directory. I want to upload only image4 since the other files are existing in S3

Day 3: Modified image2 and added a new file image5 in the local directory. I want to upload both image2 and image5 to S3

Is there a way to optimize. what needs to be uploaded instead of blindly uploading all files in the local directory.

What kind of metadata is available for an uploaded file in S3 which will allow me to make an intelligent decision here.

Comment: Look at the Linux `rsync` command.  This is its entire reason for existence.

Comment: Simply you can check the uploading file and existing file's base64 and compare it.

Comment: What have you done to do it ?

Comment: Is there a way using java ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) command:

```
aws s3 sync
```

See: [sync — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)